# Run VBA macro when cell is updated - not by user or another macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet, which uses an external add-on that updates values in a cell. Notice, the cell is not changed, only the value is updated.

I would like to run a macro every time the cell is updated.

To simulate the problem:

1. Create an empty excel sheet
2. In cell A1 add the formula '=rand()'
3. In VBA add a macro for sheet1, here a simplified version:

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
   Cells(1, 3).Value = "The function updated"
   End If

   End Sub

However, when I thereafter press F9 (to update the random numbers), the sheet does not recognize this as a sheet change, hence the macro is not run. How can I make the macro run when e.g. a random number in the sheet i updated?

Comment: You'll need a combination of the `Application.Calculate`  event to detect when the value **might** have changed and some functionality to check if the actual value of the cell(s) have changed since the event was last triggered.

Comment: I think the OP means the cell in question contains a formula that refers to other cells that are changing - but is simulating this with the `rand` function in their example.

Comment: @CLR Yes, indeed, I read the question again. I will delete my comment..

Comment: @CLR Would please give an example? I tried using the Calculate event, but it ended closing excel every time I ran an update (F9).

Comment: @Joe-Hague has given you exactly what I was describing below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would tackle this is to set a global variable pointing to the cell in question (as double) as follows:

```
    Global clvalue As Double
```

Then have a workbook open event which sets the variable to the cell value as follows:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        clvalue = Round(Sheet1.Range("C5").Value, 2)
    End Sub
```

The a worksheet Calculate event to do the comparison and resetting of the global variable to the new cell value as follows:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

        If Sheet1.Range("C5").Value <> clvalue Then
            Debug.Print clvalue
            clvalue = Sheet1.Range("C5").Value
            Debug.Print "New Global Variable is now " & clvalue
       End If
    End Sub
```